# JQuery validator how to remove error messages and add border coloring instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

```
$('.register_form').validate({


     invalidHandler: function(){

        return false;
     }
```

I've tried this but doesn't worked, how do I remove the error messages, and instead color the input border to red? didn't find examples at docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code:

```
invalidHandler: function(){
    return false;
}
```

It doesn't work because the `invalidHandler` callback has nothing to do with creating, controlling or placing the error `label` elements.  It only fires *upon submit* when the *form* is invalid.  It's simply the exact opposite of the `submitHandler` which only fires upon submit of a *valid* form.  [See documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for all callback functions.

The `errorPlacement` callback function is used to place the error message `label` elements on the page.  If you simply put a `return false` within this callback function, no error messages will be placed anywhere.

```
$('.register_form').validate({
    // rules, options, callbacks,
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, the `error` and `valid` classes will still be toggled on the field elements automatically as they are validated.  So simply use your CSS to style these as needed.

```
.error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}    
.valid {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/zqqdV/

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
errorPlacement: function(){
            return false;
        }
```

And Css:

```
.error {
    border: 2px solid #FF4000;
}

.valid {
    border: 2px solid #2EFE2E;
}
```

**Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5fY8/1/)**